# servlet for display div tag value according to changing combo box value

Tags: servlets

I want to do in my project,In combo box there are all employee Id and according to employee Id there should be display timesheet of particular employee.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `onSelectionChange` event of combobox and call the webservice or a URL of Servlet on each change event passing the id of employee and display the returned HTML on the page.

edit:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;

    public class GetEmployTimeSheet extends HttpServlet {
      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
        int emp_id = request.getParameter("empid");
        //Do database call here and get the employ timesheet data here
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Put all your time sheet here");
      }

}
```

I hope this will helo..

Comment: But I require servlet that how should I write.

Comment: Thanks.But how should I write servlet for this.